# Bind a TableView itemsProperty() to Service valueProperty()

Tags: java, javafx-2

How can I bind a `TableView` items to a running service value like in a `ListView`:

```
todoList.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

When I tried I get a compile-time error:

```
error: method bind in interface Property<T> cannot be applied to given types:
required : ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<TodoTAsk>>
found : ReadOnlyObjectProperty<List<TodoTask>>
```

**Edit**: My service class

```
public final class AllTasks extends Service<ObservableList<TodoTask>> {
    @Override
    protected Task<ObservableList<TodoTask>> createTask() {
       return new Task<ObservableList<TodoTask>>() {
          @Override
          protected ObservableList<TodoTask> call() throws Exception {
          ObservableList<TodoTask> list =      FXCollections.observableArrayList();             
         //    list.addAll(new TaskRepository().getAllTasks());
          for (TodoTask task : new TaskRepository().getAllTasks()) {
              Thread.sleep(1500);
          list.add(task);
          }
          System.out.println(list);
          return list;
        }
     }; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you define your Service?

Try something like:

```
public class MyService extends Service<ObservableList<TodoTAsk>>
```

Comment: how can I achieve a real-time update, I mean while the thread running , the `TableView` items get updated ?

Comment: Try to insert Platform.runLater in the code of your Service to update incrementally your control. After this, there is no need to bind the service.

Comment: @AntonioJ. the responsibility of service is to load items from the database and not updating the `UI`.

Comment: Yes, @tarrsalah, you are right. But I understand you that you want to update the UI at the same time you are retrieving your results. From the service, I just know the value property, but will fill the component after the service finish.